# Filtering database with libsodium encryption

Tags: php, mysql

I have encrypted some fields from my database with libsodium.
On view, I decrypt the values.

I'm stuck on a search based on a MySQL query -> "where model like '$val'". This query is from a filter where I try to find, let's say, names like `$val` from db.

How can I achieve this while my DB is encrypted?

Comment: _"How can I achieve this?"_ You would have to sequentially scan and decrypt every row on the client side. Is this `model` field like a model number for a part? Why would you encrypt that?

Comment: Problem is i dont want to get all the rows then decrypt and do the finding. And right now the system goes like this
$model->where etc etc and way down in the script is a get collection method on the model, that retrieves the result. I was eondering if theres another way to achieve this.

Comment: You have two options: 1) Don't encrypt the data. 2) Scan all the rows.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If i somehow come across a solution other than yours i will post it here. Until then, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- Create a model that deals with temporary tables
- Store the model you want to decrypt to the temporary model
- Decrypt the temporary table and return the rows
- Do the query (where x = $value) on the temporary model and return the ids of the original model
- Query the original model with the ids
- Display results

Reasons for this solution:

1. You create a function that will be called whenever you need
2. Temporary tables, faster querie
3. Minimum edits on the existing search methods

Other solution:

Look it up for libsodium blind index, involves adding new rows to the existing table and searching is done by the blind index value.